# Angular apply scope changes from global function cause unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3gd8a/1/

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("index", []);

    app.run(function ($log, $controller) {
        $log_service = $log;
        $controller_service = $controller;
    });

    app.controller("AlertsController", function () {
        this.alerts = [ "first alert" ];
        this.innerFunction = function() {
            this.alerts.push("inner alert");
            $log_service.debug(alerts.alerts);
        };
    });
})();

function outerFunction() {
    var alerts = $controller_service("AlertsController");
    alerts.alerts.push("outer alert");
    $log_service.debug(alerts.alerts);
};
```

In this example I changed the property of controller instance in the outer js function,

now I don't known how can I apply it just like use $scope.apply().

I already read angular-tips watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest,

$scope has the $apply function, but controller instance didn't have one.

You may want to ask why I use controller instance not $scope, because I learn angular js from [codeschool](http://www.codeschool.com) so I want use the same way I learned if possible.

And you may want to ask why not use ng-click, I known use ng-click will work but I want figure out how angular js watch properties of controller instance and how to apply the changes of them manually.

Edit:

I figured out controller instance is just a property named `alerts` under $scope when I use it by `ng-controller="AlertsController as alerts"`.

Now I had another problem, If I access $scope from outerFunction will cause an error.

The first time is `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope angular.js:78`

And the second time is
`Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$injector/cdep?p0=`

Comment: Version after edit: http://jsfiddle.net/3gd8a/5/

Comment: Finally version http://jsfiddle.net/3gd8a/6/, I should get scope by the element under controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answer, I leave my answer here.

Controller instance is a object under $scope after initiazlied, in the example I alias `AlertsController` to `alerts` so it named `alerts` under $scope.

Then `$scope.alerts` and `this` are equivalent.

In the first comment (http://jsfiddle.net/3gd8a/5) I tried put $scope to global then access it from `outerFunction` but failed, I still need figure out why.

In the second comment (http://jsfiddle.net/3gd8a/6) I found $scope can get from the element inside of controller, and it's can be access normally.

So the way to update and apply property of controller instance from global function is

1. add id to any element inside controller
2. use `angular.element` find that element then call `.scope()` to get the scope.
3. use `scope.{alias of controller}.{property name}` to update property, then call `$scope.apply` to apply.